# How to compare time from MySQL to the current time in php

Tags: php, mysql

Helllo, I have end_time stored in the database. If I do $row['end_time'] it will give me a string. in format '2013:10:20 10:10:21' How can I convert this string to the time format and compare to the current time?
my goal is to build an 'if' statement that would compare the current time with the time from the database.
Can someone show me the trick?
Thank you!

Comment: You can do it in SQL too: `where end_time > now()` for instance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php

$end_time = new DateTime('2013:10:20 10:10:21');
$now = new DateTime();

if( $end_time<$now ){
    echo 'Expired';
}
```

You can find all reference in the [Date and Time](https://www.php.net/datetime) chapter.